# How do I change the style of an existing Wordpress menu to be Floated and horizontal?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

Please check : http://shoejunction.net/
In the top menu, if you put your cursor on Shoes by Brand, it will show a really long list of items. 
I want these items to be in a floating square drop down. So it will fit inside the page (the top menu goes down with you if you scroll down the page).

Is it possible to change it's style to do that?
I tried Mega Menu plugin, but it changes the style of the menu, and i want to keep the style.

Thanks.

Comment: An example in jsfiddle or codepen would be great :)

Comment: I don't know what that is :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/, and http://codepen.io/, are good tools to put code and check results, widely used in StackOverflow.

Comment: Good to know, but you can just checkout my problem on the site itself, it's wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be more specific about what you want. Here is a solution for showing all the shoes in the menu:

```
ul.sub-menu {
   max-height: 600px;
   max-height: calc(100vh - 80px); /* Comment Suggestion :D */
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Getting it to be the height of the page would require javascript though.

Comment: He could use `calc(100vh - 80px)` to achieve the full-height.

Comment: @AlexWright That is true! For compatibility sake you may want to add it as a second max-height definition so there is a fallback for incompatable browsers.

Comment: Ok that is an excellent start!, with this code the menu has a scroll bar on the right side. But I want it to wrap horizontally so it would be smaller and maybe wider, I mean, now there is a long list with 1 column, I'd like it to have a few columns so that list won't go down to the bottom of the page. like this maybe: http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Blueprint_HorizontalDropDownMenu.jpg

Comment: You would have to change the style of the ul.sub-menu>li elements need to be set to a stackable width like width:50%; the issue you run into is that the shoe menu is there is no class or id to differentiate the shoe menu. You could do #menu-top-menu>li:nth-child(2) li {width:50%;} or something like that to select that menu in particular.

Comment: to adjust the menu width you can do ----- #menu-top-menu>li:nth-child(2)>ul {
    width:300px; /* or whatever size */
} ---- Be aware though that this is going to mess with your media queries for mobile layout. You will want to wrap all of this to make it only for desktop not mobile.

Comment: nice, more progress!, now the problem is, if the window is not full size, or if it's smaller than my computer resolution, when you put your cursor on the Shoes by Brand, you can't see the third column, and you see a slider on the bottom of the window, but you can't even reach the slider cause the submenu would close if you move your cursor over there, any way to make the menu "attach" to the right side, so if the window is smaller, the user would still see the whole menu without width slider of the window?

THANKS by the way :)

Comment: If needed i can add javascript, to make it no scross the width of page if the page window is smaller. could you help me do it?

Comment: #menu-top-menu li:nth-child(2) ul {
  width: 672px;
  height: 600px;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
} Or You could use media queries if you want to find a different solution such as making it not stack horizontally when the width of the screen is less then whatever amount.